# center a layer on an imageView

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, imageview, center, layer

Hi every one here is an image from my iphone simulator to show you my problem.(at left my layer at right an image) .I add a layer as a sublayer of an imageView and I would like to center my layer on my imageView but I don't know how to do it ? Can anyone help me ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

[image from my iphone simulator](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/84/imagelayer.png/)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to set the anchor point or position of the layer you added to the center of the bounds of the image. Something along the lines of

```
[boxLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width /2, [self bounds].size.height /2)];
```